# No module named pyglet

Tags: python, import, module, pyglet

I'm having a strange issue with pyglet. After running `pip install pyglet` and restarting my command line application, I'm still unable to run a python script that imports pyglet.

Error output:

```
$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pyglet import image
ImportError: No module named pyglet
```

Running pip install pyglet again gives:

```
pip install pyglet
--> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): 
    pyglet in c:\python34\lib\site-packages
```

This is on a Windows 7 machine running Python 2.7, and the script in question can be found here: https://github.com/fogleman/Minecraft/blob/master/main.py

What's the matter with pyglet?

Comment: What do you mean *"unable to run"*? Are you trying to run it in the same environment you've installed `pyglet` in?

Comment: are you able to import pyglet alone? Are you using any virtual environment maybe?

Comment: Can you show an error message? And, preferably, result of running `pip install pyglet`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This line

```
pyglet in c:\python34\lib\site-packages
                   ^
```

means that you installed module for python 3.4. You need to install it for 2.7 instead:

```
python2.7 -m pip install pyglet
```

or, which is more reliable in your case

```
python -m pip install pyglet
```

Answer (score -1):

i think that u should reinstall pip for a newer version and with the "satisfy" error usually comes up when u have a module already installed.

Comment: Is this just a guess or based on facts? Did you had the same error got solved with this?

Comment: yep ive got the same error when i had python 3.6