# Why isn't UniCurses for Python working?

Tags: python, linux, import

I'm trying to make my first UniCurses project with Python on OpenSUSE.
I put the import statement in my .py file, but when I tried to run it, it says the module is not there... So I downloaded UniCurses from the website, and the instructions say Unix's Python already has UniCurses. That's odd, but I continued. I put the downloaded unicurses.py into my project directory, and when I tried running my file, an error message says UniCurses is not compatible with my system, and that either my Python distribution is below v2.6 or my operating system is something other than Windows or a *nix. My Python is v2.7.8, and again, my OS is a Linux distro. Why is this happening, and what should I do?

Edit: It's worth noting that the regular curses supposedly doesn't work on my system either.

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268953/how-to-install-python-package-from-github

Comment: I tried using pip install git+https://github.com/Chiel92/unicurses and it didn't work. The download activated, but I still can't run my .py, and the error message still claims my platform is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by [Sagar Rakshe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1315878/sagar-rakshe) from [How to install Python package from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268953/how-to-install-python-package-from-github):

> To install Python package from github, you need to clone that repository.
>
> `git clone https://github.com/jkbr/httpie.git`
>
> Then just run the setup.py file from that directory,
>
> `sudo python setup.py install`

If you have already downloaded the file you can skip the first step and just run the `python setup.py install` in the folder. (I don't think `sudo` is necessary for python)

Comment: I tried that. It "installed" but I still get the same error. Also I have a similar problem with pip; even though it's installed, when I try using it (to install Pyglet), the terminal claims there is no module named pip.

Comment: I was trying to use the solution someone gave here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613258/no-module-named-pyglet

Comment: pip is a python module. try it: `python -m pip`

Comment: @Pod yes I have learned that since I posted this answer and have deleted my comment that stated it was not a module since it is wrong, Thank you though.